# Where can I actually see a root node in Javafx?

Tags: javafx

I know did lots and lots of reading and they keep saying the same thing. A root node doesn't have any parent nodes but only have children nodes.

1. If I only have stage and a scene but zero node, would I still have a root node by default?
2. If I have two nodes, one is a circle and the other is a square, which one is a root node?

Answer (score 4):

> If I only have stage and a scene but zero node

This is impossible. There is no constructor for a [`Scene`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html) that doesn't take a `root` node parameter (and if you pass `null`, you simply get a `NullPointerException`). So if you have a scene, you necessarily have a root node.

> If I have two nodes, one is a circle and the other is a square, which one is a root node?

Neither, since neither is an instance of `Parent`, and the `root` property of `Scene` is a `Parent`.

The only way to display any node is to either have it as the root of a scene, or to have it as a child of the root, or the child of a child of the root, etc.

So if the `Circle` and square (presumably a `Rectangle`) are both displayed, they must both be descendants of some root node.

Comment: if I have a scene, I necessarily have a root node, as in a 'pane' for example? I understand that a pane is necessary as a parameter of a the Scene but isn't pane a parent , opposed to a node? if I remember correct, I have read on many tutorials that a 'parent' and a 'node' are different things.

Comment: A [`Parent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/Parent.html) is a (special kind of, i.e. subclass of) `Node`. Not every `Node` is a `Parent` (e.g. `Circle` is a `Node`, but is not a `Parent`). Specifically, a `Parent` is a `Node` that contains other `Node`s.

Comment: Yes. `Pane` is a subclass of `Parent`, and `Parent` is a subclass of `Node`.

Comment: @NewLearner Would probably be good to read up on composite design pattern.

Comment: Thank you. so where can I actually see root node? is root node a class? is it like an interface where only intangible abstract rules exist and actual object of  it does not exist?

Comment: @NewLearner treat the "root node" like you do oxygen. You don't have to see it in order to use it. Also, as long as you use it correctly, everything will be alright. `Scene scene = new Scene(yourRootNodeGoesHere);`

Comment: Sedrick: Scene scene = new Scene(yourRootNode); it can't be right because it's usually Scene scene = new Scene(pane); at least when I code. so which means pane is my root node but according to other previous comments, pane(which is an object to class Pane) is not my root node.

Comment: @NewLearner In contrast to `Node`, `Parent`, `Rectangle`, `Circle` and `Pane` *"root node"* is not a type but a term used for the node that is used as the root of a scene (i.e. it's the value of the [`root` property of your scene](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#rootProperty)). Sedrik was simply using `yourRootNodeGoesHere` as placeholder for any expression you want to use as the root of the scene.

Comment: @fabian I see. So a root node is just a node that is used as the root which means a 'root node' is one individual 'node'. If that's the case, if my code has a stage, scene, and an 'empty pane' that has zero node inside the pane, then, technically, that code(which just shows an empty popup box) does not have a root node. correct?

Comment: It has a root node which is the empty pane. As James mentioned showing a scene with a `null` root does not work. The constructor parameter of scene with type `Parent` is assigned to the root property.

Comment: @fabian so is a root node one individual node? Because you said it was and now it sounds like you're saying it's not. also you said "root node which is the empty pane", so now are you saying that a root node is a pane ? but a pane is a subclass of Parent, which means that what you said doesn't really add up.

Comment: @NewLearner Not sure if you're genuinely misunderstanding, or just trolling at this point. In the specific example you cited, the root node of that particular scene would be the empty `Pane` that you passed to the scene's constructor. `Pane` is a subclass of `Parent`, so this works. Every scene's root node has to be an instance of `Parent`; in the specific case you cited the specific instance of `Parent` is the empty pane.